# Use jq to rename object keys

Tags: json, jq

I have something that is probably simple for someone with experience with jq.  I have a file.txt with this in it:

{"user1": 10, "joe": 13, "jane": 55}

I would like to format this so that it produces the following result:

```
cat file.txt |jq \<???\>

{
"user.user1": 10,
"user.joe": 13,
"user.jane": 55,
}
```

My goal is to be able to query by something like "user = user.*" and get a result of all the users because the specific usernames will vary.

This is as far as I have been able to get:

```
cat file.txt |jq --arg v 'user' --arg k 'key'  '\[.\]| to_entries\[\]|.\[$k\] = $v'
{
"key": "user",
"value": {
"user1": 10,
"joe": 13,
"jane": 55
}
}
```

But that does not give me the ability to query by user.

Comment: I need to modify the question.  I just realized that the cleaner way to do this is if I have users that holds an array of user and number.  So for example, I would like to get the following results:

`{ "users":
  [
    "user1": 10,
    "joe": 13,
    "jane": 55
  ]
}`

Comment: Your new desired formatting is not valid JSON (you are using array brackets `[…]` but inside you have object definitions `… : …`. Maybe you want this: `jq --arg u 'user' '{($u): .}' file.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with_entries`, and update `|=` the `.key`:

```bash
jq --arg u 'user' 'with_entries(.key |= $u + "." + .)' file.txt
```

```json
{
  "user.user1": 10,
  "user.joe": 13,
  "user.jane": 55
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work.  However, I just realized that I still  cannot query this the way I want.  Instead of adding the user to the result like that, would it be possible to format the output like this:

{ “users” [
  “user1": 10,
  "joe": 13,
  "jane": 55
 ]
}

Comment: You could query this result using `… | jq --arg u 'user' 'with_entries(select((.key / ".")[0] == $u))'` or `… | jq -r --arg u 'user' 'keys[] | select(startswith($u + ".")) | ltrimstr($u + ".")'` (depending on what kind of output you want). Your new desired formatting is not valid JSON (you are using array brackets `[…]` but inside you have object definitions `… : …`. Maybe you want this: `jq --arg u 'user' '{($u): .}' file.txt`